# Cannot access smtp.gmail.com 465

Tags: gmail, cmd, telnet

When is use the command on my cmd:

```
telnet smtp.gmail.com 465
```

[image]

The cmd just goes blank:

[image]

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't blank - it is actually waiting for you to issue telnet commands. Press CTRL and ']' key - it will take you to Telnet command window. Key in 'h' to find a list of telnet commands.

For specific SMTP commands follow commands under "SMTP transport example" in the [wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol).

Comment: Shouldn't it display a greeting message before accepting commands?

Comment: @AndriyM yes, it will when you press CTRL + ']' key (on any Windows). I am not sure if the behavior is different on other platforms.

Comment: @Slackware CTRL + "]" (not J, the square bracket close key)